# Disable the Navigation of the TabBar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to disable the Navigation of a TabBarController?

Background: I want to do the event handling by myself...

```
        ViewControllerSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Take action based on the tab being selected
            switch (TabBar.SelectedItem.Title)
            {
                case "Test":
                    // Do something... like your own navigation
                    break;
            }
        };
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? If you want to handle the navigation yourself, then why doesn't your current implementation work?

Comment: Tank you, you are right - in general the current implementation works. The problem is, that the "normal" navigation (after clicking on a tab) also gets executed... Is there a possibility to avoid this?

Comment: Instead of bending a great working controller and abuse it for something it was not designed for, you should maybe consider creating your own Tab-Alike-Bar-Controller.

Comment: Ok. I think you are right. Thanks